# Google API using Oauth for internal company use only

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-oauth

I've created a web application using Node.js that relies on a google API (specifically the DCM/DFA reporting API). It redirects the user to login to their gmail account, and after a successful login redirects back to the web application.

Suddenly my company has told me that this web application needs to be restricted to internal use only, and that they won't host it on a public domain for security reasons.

Is there any way to get Oauth to redirect to the internal domain? When I try to set the redirect domain in the google developers console I get an error message that it is not valid. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: you need to also add this domain in google API console, there is a list of valid redirect_uris. Your browser will then get your url, but it will only be possible to view it in your company ( or whatever you call 'internal use' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample redirect url you can add at Console and Code is:

http://localhost:8080/authcallback

(Remember to not add trailing / in url)